# Python - TensorArray has size zero, but element shape [?,128] is not fully defined

Tags: python, tensorflow

Trying to run: https://github.com/huseinzol05/Stock-Prediction-Models/blob/master/deep-learning/17.lstm-seq2seq-bidirectional-attention.ipynb

With the data: https://gist.github.com/TensorTom/d37f4bd605d6a13dfc75015c5e150b82

But this happens during training epochs (Or just at or after the last epoch):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333     try:
-> 1334       return fn(*args)
   1335     except errors.OpError as e:

/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1318       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1319           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1320 

/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1406         self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1407         run_metadata)
   1408 

UnimplementedError: TensorArray has size zero, but element shape [?,128] is not fully defined. Currently only static shapes are supported when packing zero-size TensorArrays.
     [[{{node decoder/bidirectional_rnn/fw/fw/TensorArrayStack/TensorArrayGatherV3}}]]
     [[{{node decoder/bidirectional_rnn/bw/bw/while/Exit_3}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-07a23d0b1dbd> in <module>
     22         modelnn.X: np.expand_dims(df_log.iloc[upper_b:], axis = 0),
     23         modelnn.backward_hidden_layer: init_value_backward,
---> 24         modelnn.forward_hidden_layer: init_value_forward,
     25     },
     26 )

/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    927     try:
    928       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 929                          run_metadata_ptr)
    930       if run_metadata:
    931         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1150     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1151       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1152                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1153     else:
   1154       results = []

/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1326     if handle is None:
   1327       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1328                            run_metadata)
   1329     else:
   1330       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1346           pass
   1347       message = error_interpolation.interpolate(message, self._graph)
-> 1348       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1349 
   1350   def _extend_graph(self):

UnimplementedError: TensorArray has size zero, but element shape [?,128] is not fully defined. Currently only static shapes are supported when packing zero-size TensorArrays.
     [[node decoder/bidirectional_rnn/fw/fw/TensorArrayStack/TensorArrayGatherV3 (defined at <ipython-input-5-7fc0ccd4ec49>:97) ]]
     [[node decoder/bidirectional_rnn/bw/bw/while/Exit_3 (defined at <ipython-input-5-7fc0ccd4ec49>:97) ]]

Caused by op 'decoder/bidirectional_rnn/fw/fw/TensorArrayStack/TensorArrayGatherV3', defined at:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 505, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 539, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1775, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 758, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1233, in inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1147, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 370, in dispatch_queue
    yield self.process_one()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 346, in wrapper
    runner = Runner(result, future, yielded)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1080, in __init__
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1147, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 357, in process_one
    yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 267, in dispatch_shell
    yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 534, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 294, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 536, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2819, in run_cell
    raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2845, in _run_cell
    return runner(coro)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 67, in _pseudo_sync_runner
    coro.send(None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3020, in run_cell_async
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3185, in run_ast_nodes
    if (yield from self.run_code(code, result)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-6-2e75d5202b26>", line 2, in <module>
    modelnn = Model(0.01, num_layers, df_log.shape[1], size_layer, df_log.shape[1], dropout_rate)
  File "<ipython-input-5-7fc0ccd4ec49>", line 97, in __init__
    dtype = tf.float32,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 443, in bidirectional_dynamic_rnn
    time_major=time_major, scope=fw_scope)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 671, in dynamic_rnn
    dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 883, in _dynamic_rnn_loop
    final_outputs = tuple(ta.stack() for ta in output_final_ta)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 883, in <genexpr>
    final_outputs = tuple(ta.stack() for ta in output_final_ta)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py", line 1128, in stack
    return self._implementation.stack(name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py", line 292, in stack
    return self.gather(math_ops.range(0, self.size()), name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py", line 306, in gather
    element_shape=element_shape)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 6291, in tensor_array_gather_v3
    element_shape=element_shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3300, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1801, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

UnimplementedError (see above for traceback): TensorArray has size zero, but element shape [?,128] is not fully defined. Currently only static shapes are supported when packing zero-size TensorArrays.
     [[node decoder/bidirectional_rnn/fw/fw/TensorArrayStack/TensorArrayGatherV3 (defined at <ipython-input-5-7fc0ccd4ec49>:97) ]]
     [[node decoder/bidirectional_rnn/bw/bw/while/Exit_3 (defined at <ipython-input-5-7fc0ccd4ec49>:97) ]]
```

So I talked to someone about this who was using the same script and they suggested that it was because my dataset was too many lines; that they were able to avoid this error by limiting the lines of data to 400 lines. This did indeed get rid of the error but it doesn't solve the problem.

Using < 400 lines is fine for 1 day per-line OHLCV data but if I want to use a lower timeframe, say, 1minute per-line OHLCV data, 400 lines isn't going to cut it.

How can I get this model to accept an arbitrary rows of data?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am getting exactly the same error when executing for the Deep Learning 1 (LSTM) notebook in the Stock Prediction Repo. If you could resolve it, any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: when using say 25 rows, the same error persists. I don't know why the model isn't able to take more rows compared to the GOOG dataset the repo uses. Its really weird and if you managed to solve this, please do post it as an answer to this question.

Comment: still no joy on this

Comment: Hey! Did you guys solve this question? I am getting the same error and I am definitely sure I am not send any empty data.